# Custom component within scrollview

Tags: android, custom-component

I have a custom component that is vertically longer than the screen height and I'm trying to make it scroll. In my onDraw method, I'm drawing the shapes unto a fixed coordinates, and it seems that the content doesn't change even when I scroll. Do I need to draw the shapes unto a different coordinates based on the scrolled position? If so, how do I retrieve the current scroll position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to handle any scrolling from your end, then add your customView to ScrollView. If you want to handle the scroll from your end then you can refer to thebelow link which is for 2Dscroll which handles both Horizontal and Vertical Scrolls.

[Android Two-Dimensional ScrollView](http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the question. I already do have my custom component inside a scrollview. However, nothing changes when I scroll up/down. I was wondering whether I need to handle the change in scroll position and draw differently in my onDraw method or not.

Comment: No need to handle any thing. Can you please try by hard coding the width and height of the CustomView. This is the problem because of the OnMeasure in the custom view. You should specify the proper width and height of the CustomView. I tried this in my project and is working fine. So no need to bother about other things if you properly created your CustomView.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't handing onMeasure properly